# insert EOF statement before the last line of file

Tags: text-processing, sed, cat, gnu

I want to insert this

```
cat <<EOF >> /etc/security/limits.conf
*    soft     nproc       65535    
*    hard     nproc       65535   
*    soft     nofile      65535   
*    hard     nofile      65535
root soft     nproc       65535
root hard     nproc       65535
root soft     nofile      65535
root hard     nofile      65535
EOF
```

into the second to last line of the file, before the `# End of file` line.

I know I could use other methods to insert this statement without the use of `EOF` but for visual candy I wanted to maintain this format as well for readability.

Comment: The method above just appends to file. So without a tool that can recognize the `# End of file` line there's probably no better way to make it work. Such tool would be either `awk` or `sed`. I'd recommend a 2 step process: delete the line via `sed -i '/# End of file/d'` and then insert the data you want with `# End of file` added to original `cat` command you have there, or via third step - `echo  '# End of file' >> /etc/security/limits.conf`.

Comment: Let me know if you want that as an answer and not just comment

Comment: I'm unclear on the requirements: do you want to insert all 10 lines into some other undisclosed file? Or are you saying that you want to append the 8 lines of data into the limits.conf file, but just not at the end of that file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ex` (which is a [mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#Ex) of the `vi` editor) to accomplish this.

You can use the [`:read`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#:read) command to insert the contents into the file. That command takes a filename, but you can use the `/dev/stdin` pseudo-device to read from standard input, which allows you to use a `<<EOF` marker.

The `:read` command also takes a range, and you can use the `$-` symbol, which breaks down into `$`, which indicates the last line of the file, and `-` to subtract one from it, getting to the second to last line of the file. (You could use `$-1` as well.)

Putting it all together:

```
$ ex -s /etc/security/limits.conf -c '$-r /dev/stdin' -c 'wq' <<EOF
*    soft     nproc       65535    
*    hard     nproc       65535   
*    soft     nofile      65535   
*    hard     nofile      65535
root soft     nproc       65535
root hard     nproc       65535
root soft     nofile      65535
root hard     nofile      65535
EOF
```

The `-s` is to make it silent (not switch into visual mode, which would make the screen blink.) The `$-r` is abbreviated (a full `$-1read` would have worked as well) and finally the `wq` is how you write and quit in `vi`. :-)

---

**UPDATE:** If instead of inserting before the last line, you want to insert before a line with specific contents (such as "# End of file"), then just use a `/search/` pattern to do so.

For example:

```
$ ex -s /etc/security/limits.conf -c '/^# End of file/-1r /dev/stdin' -c 'wq' <<EOF
...
EOF
```

Answer (score 7):

To keep the same sort of here-document format and to insert the given text immediately before the last line of the file, try ed!

```
ed -s /etc/security/limits.conf << EOF
$ i
*    soft     nproc       65535    
*    hard     nproc       65535   
*    soft     nofile      65535   
*    hard     nofile      65535
root soft     nproc       65535
root hard     nproc       65535
root soft     nofile      65535
root hard     nofile      65535
.
wq
EOF
```

This sends a sequence of commands to ed, all in a here-document. We address the last line in the file with `$` and say that we would like to `i`nsert some text. The text follows, just as in your example; once we're done with the inserted text, we tell ed we're done with a single period (`.`).  `W`rite the file back to disk and then `q`uit.

If you wanted to collapse the `$ i` to `$i` you'd want to escape the dollar sign or use a quoted here-document (`ed -s input << 'EOF' ...`) to prevent `$i` from expanding to the current vale of the `i` variable or empty if there's no such variable set.

Answer (score 0):

Another method: print all but the last line of the file, print the new text, then print the last line of the file. Then redirect all that output to a new file.

```
{
    sed '$d' limits.conf
    cat <<EOF
*    soft     nproc       65535
*    hard     nproc       65535
*    soft     nofile      65535
*    hard     nofile      65535
root soft     nproc       65535
root hard     nproc       65535
root soft     nofile      65535
root hard     nofile      65535
EOF
    tail -1 limits.conf
} > tmpfile && mv tmpfile limits.conf
```